# How find the minimum of the value of $n$ such $n^2\equiv 1\pmod{1007}$

Tags: number-theory

let $n>1$ is positive integers,How find the minimum value of $n$,such

> $$n^2-1\equiv 0\pmod {1007}$$

My try:

> $$n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$$
>   and $1007=19\cdot 53$

so I guess $n_\min=1006$, But How prove it?

Comment: There is no minimum. But the minimum *positive* is $1$.

Comment: Am i missing someting? $1$ will do

Comment: @Andre Nicolas, the OP said $n\in\mathbf{Z}^+$, so $n=1$ is the minimum.

Comment: I think, If you will go for minimum, then hard to predict, because even if n is negative $ n^2 $ will be positive, hence it is difficult to get minimum, off course minimum positive is 1.

Comment: Hello,everyone,$n$ is postive integer number,and $n>1$,Thank you everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want $x^2\equiv1\pmod{19}$ and $x^2\equiv1\pmod{53}$ simultaneously. There are four cases:
$x\equiv1\pmod{19}$ & $x\equiv1\pmod{53}$, or $x\equiv-1\pmod{19}$ & $x\equiv-1\pmod{53}$, or $x\equiv1\pmod{19}$ & $x\equiv-1\pmod{53}$, or $x\equiv-1\pmod{19}$ & $x\equiv1\pmod{53}$. The solutions to the first two cases are obviously $x\equiv1\pmod{1007}$ and $x\equiv-1\equiv1006\pmod{1007}$. The solutions to the other two cases are $x\equiv476\pmod{1007}$ and $x\equiv-476\equiv531\pmod{1007}$. I think the one you want is $476$.

Here's how you can solve the simultaneous congruences $x\equiv1\pmod{19}$ & $x\equiv-1\pmod{53}$. Write $x=53t-1$ from the second congruence and substitute in the first congruence:
$$53t-1\equiv1\pmod{19}$$$$-4t\equiv2\pmod{19}$$$$-20t\equiv10\pmod{19}$$$$-t\equiv10\pmod{19}$$$$t\equiv-10\pmod{19}$$$$t\equiv9\pmod{19}$$$$t=9+19u$$$$x=53t-1=53(9+19u)-1=476+1007u$$$$x\equiv476\pmod{1007}$$

Comment: Thank you, why other two cases are $x\equiv 476(mod 1007)$?

Comment: and $n$ is minimum $476$? How prove it $476$ is minimum ? Thank you

Comment: The four solutions $\pmod{1007}$ are $1$, $476$, $531$, and $1006$, so the minimum solution $\gt1$ is $476$.

Comment: Or you have $x=19k+1=53\ell -1$, so you need to solve in integers $53\ell-19k=2$, which can be done using extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

If $N:=1007$ were prime then $N-1=1006$ would be the answer because
$N \mid (n+1)(n-1)$ would imply $N \mid n+1$ or $N \mid n-1$.
But since we're given that $N=pq$ for some primes $p=19$, $q=53$ 
it's also possible to have $p \mid n+1$ and $q \mid n-1$ or vice versa
Each of these leads to a "Chinese remainder" problem; if "china math" 
knows how to solve such an equation already then it's enough to exhibit 
the other two solutions $n=\pm 476$ 
(e.g. $476$ is $+1 \bmod p$ and $-1 \bmod q$).

[Or, of course, you could cheat and just have a computer try
all $n=2,3,\ldots,N-1$:
in **gp** the command
**n=2; while((n^2-1)%1007,n++); n** returns **476** in under a millisecond.]